# Entity Data Model doesn´t show MySql option

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Im using xampp xampp-win32-5.6.15-1-VC11-installer.exe, and MySQL Connector Net 6.6.4

I add the following files to my MVC project

- MySql.Data
- MySql.Data.Entity
- MySql.Web

[image]

My web.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación de ASP.NET, visite
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>

      <system.web>

        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
      </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

      <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers></system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

When I try to add Entity Data model, the MySql option is not there.

Answer (score 2):

You need the mySQL data connectors and MySQL for Visual Studio.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-install.html

Make sure to follow the instructions about install ordering. I've had that cause issues in the past.

Comment: I unistall the old MySQL Connector Net 6.6.4 that I was used and then I install new version 6.8.7 but the error continue, I´m using visual Studio 2013

Comment: I try to add this line to my web.config to:<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

Comment: The connectors should be compatible w/ 2013. Have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html

Comment: The connector that I use now is 6.8 that is supported by visual studio 2013, I try to do the same as the last link that you pass me but  the error continue, the new connection data base doesn´t show me the mysql opcion.

Comment: MySQL for Visual Studio enables mysqldatabase option in server explorer and mySQL data connectors enables the same under Entity data model wizard.